# ChartJS xAxis time formats don't change for days

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a ChartJS chart, showing data in time.

I am using the following time formats:

```
displayFormats: {
  millisecond: 'mm:ss',
  second: 'mm:ss',
  minute: 'HH:mm',
  hour: 'HH:mm',
  day: 'MMM DD',
  week: 'MMM DD',
  month: 'YYYY MMM',
  quarter: 'YYYY MMM',
  year: 'YYYY',
}
```

I let the user choose from multiple options:

- Last Hour
- Last Day
- Last Week
- Last Month

When doing 'Last Hour', the output is good. Using `minute`
[image]

When doing `Last Day`, the output is good. Using `hour`
[image]

When doing `Last Week`, the output is really bad. I even tried 9 days, but it is using `hour` again
[image]

And to show it is not "stuck" on hour, when doing a month, the output is good. Using `day`.
[image]

Now while I do understand why it does that (it wants an amount of labels, and there are more labels than days so it goes to hours), I am not sure how to fix it.

I want on week for it to show the `day` format. Is there a way I can achieve that with ChartJS?

I am not sure this helps, but the amount of datapoints I show for each screen varies, and can be 5,000 - 50,000, and also is not known in advance.

**Bonus**
It is super annoying that on the right side it sometimes creates a label on top of a label because of the amount of steps it creates. Is there a way to fix that as well?

Comment: Can you set up a sample fiddle which demonstrates this? Want to understand your chart config and input data, specifically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to coerce the units you want the xAxis to use using the `unit` property. For example, if you wanted it to show it in terms of days instead of hours you can use a config like:

```
var chart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                time: {
                    unit: 'day',
                    displayFormats: {
                        day: 'MMM DD' 
                    }
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

An alternative would be to use `minUnit` instead of `unit`. This will ensure your graph scales up better as it will limit the lowest display format to use while still being flexible to use larger formats if needed.

With regard to your overlapping labels problem, tweaking the `unitStepSize` property might help.

More information in the [Time Units Section](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/time.html#time-units) of ChartJS docs

Comment: This is great. It doesn't change in real time, so I can't just switch the unit for it, but it does work if I determine in advance. So this solves this question, and now I'll just figure out how to reload the chart options without reloading the entire chart.